# TapGestureRecognizer doesn`t work on Xamarin Map

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im used similar gesture recognizer on Image and it worked. But on a
 map nothing work. What could be the reason? Im testing it on Droid project.

```
 public class MapPage : ContentPage
    {
     Map map;
     public MapPage()
     {
        map = new ExtendedMap
        {
            IsShowingUser = true,
            HeightRequest = 100,
            WidthRequest = 940,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };           
        map.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            Command = new Command(()=> { OnAlertYesNoClicked(null, null); }),
            NumberOfTapsRequired = 1
        });
        ContentLayout.Children.Add(map);
    }

    void NavClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsShowRightPanel = !IsShowRightPanel;
    }

    async void OnAlertYesNoClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var answer = await DisplayAlert("Question?", "Would you like to play a game", "Yes", "No");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it is not fired, but I can imagine it's not working because the map itself catches tap events etc.

I see you are using the `ExtendedMap`, have a look at [TKCustomMap](https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap) instead. It has a property for a `Command` to invoke code when the map is tapped.